# go mysql returning null values

Tags: mysql, go

I am currently working on a Golang Google App Engine Project and have run into a small problem. I have a database "party" with table "parties". The problem is that when the following code is executed, a EMPTY json array is printed - it actually is properly long, but it only contains empty Parties. (And I do have entries in my database)

Go code (not all of it):

```
func getParties(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    rows := getRowsFromSql("select * from parties;")
    parties := scanForParties(rows)

    json, _ := json.Marshal(parties)
    fmt.Fprint(w, string(json))
}

func scanForParties(rows *sql.Rows) []Party {
    var parties []Party

    for rows.Next() {
        var id int
        var name, author, datetime, datetime_to, host, location, description, longtitude, latitude, primary_image_id string
        rows.Scan(&id, &name, &author, &datetime, &datetime_to, &host, &location, &description, &longtitude, &latitude, &primary_image_id)
        party := Party{
            Id:           id,
            Name:         name,
            Author:       author,
            Datetime:     datetime,
            Datetime_to:  datetime_to,
            Host:         host,
            Location:     location,
            Description:  description,
            Longtitude:   longtitude,
            Latitude:     latitude,
            PrimaryImgId: primary_image_id,
        }
        parties = append(parties, party)
    }

    return parties
}

func getRowsFromSql(query string) *sql.Rows {
    con, err := sql.Open("mysql", dbConnectString)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer con.Close()

    rows, err2 := con.Query(query)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }
    return rows

}

type Party struct {
    Id           int
    Name         string
    Author       string
    Datetime     string
    Datetime_to  string
    Host         string
    Location     string
    Description  string
    Longtitude   string
    Latitude     string
    PrimaryImgId string
}
```

And my parties table:

```
mysql> describe parties;
+------------------+----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field            | Type           | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+------------------+----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id               | int(11)        | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| name             | varchar(64)    | NO   |     |                   |                             |
| author           | varchar(64)    | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| datetime         | datetime       | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| last_edited      | timestamp      | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| datetime_to      | datetime       | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| host             | text           | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| location         | text           | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| description      | text           | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| longitude        | decimal(23,20) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| latitude         | decimal(23,20) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| primary_image_id | varchar(256)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
+------------------+----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

However, this old version of code works just fine:

```
func getParties(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    con, dbErr := sql.Open("mysql", dbConnectString)

    defer con.Close()

    if dbErr == nil {
        rows, _ := con.Query("select id, name, author, datetime from parties where datetime >= NOW();")

        var parties []Party

        var id int
        var name string
        var author string
        var datetime string

        for rows.Next() {
            rows.Scan(&id, &name, &author, &datetime)
            party := Party{}
            party.Id = id
            party.Name = name
            party.Author = author
            party.Datetime = datetime
            parties = append(parties, party)
        }

        if len(parties) > 0 {
            json, _ := json.Marshal(parties)
            fmt.Fprint(w, string(json))
        } else {
            fmt.Fprint(w, "{}")
        }

    } else {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "{\"Error\"}")
    }
}
```

Any idea why this happens?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: **Never** ignore `error` returns! IMO it's not even worth looking at this until you add at least minimal error checking.

Comment: is there any error ignored, beside the one that may occur when parsing json (which is not a problem - believe me, I checked)?

Comment: You checked once maybe. If it's not checked in the code no one (even you) knows that some error isn't happening there now.

Comment: In particular, `rows.Scan` returns an `error` value.

Comment: Side notes: share the results from `db.Open`, don't close and re-open it. It'd be easier to do `p := Party{}` (or `var p Party`) and then use things like `&p.id` in the scan.

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, but I'm thinking that it's because you're closing the connection to the database here:

```
defer con.Close()
```

This will close the connection to the database when `getRowsFromSql` returns, so by the time you start calling `rows.Next()` in `scanForParties` the DB connection is gone. Once the DB connection is closed, any collection of rows will no longer be available.

Something is probably returning an `error` because of this, but since you're not checking any errors anywhere you won't know. In Go it is idiomatic to check for errors whenever a function can return one (and other languages too, just more so in Go because of the lack of exceptions).

Answer (score 1):

Okay so all the others were right about the errors: rows.Scan() returns an error. And when I finally checked it, it said that there are insufficient scan variables provided. Simple fix: add the missing one.

Thank you guys :)